# C3.js - On window resize, how do I change legend position from right to bottom?

Tags: d3.js, mobile, charts, responsive, c3.js

I'm attempting to update my c3 legend on my pie graph when browser is resized below a certain size. Also cannot target via css as the graph is svg and creates groups which we cannot target. eg svg g { ...

Here is my attempt to hide and show the legend using the c3 function legend.hide(); This attempt works on first load (remove resize function) but I want this to be dynamic so if browser is resized manually then hide/show legend dependent on rules.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 650) {
    chart.legend.hide();
      console.log('plz hide!');
    } else {
      chart.legend.show();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onresize property:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: d3.select('.chart'),
    onresize: function () {
      //your code to change labels here
    },
    data: {
     ...
    }
});
```

You can also check c3.js docs [here](https://c3js.org/reference.html#onresize)